# How can I corrrect 404 NOT FOUND error, resulting from a view, route, controller scheme in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I am seeing **404 NOT FOUND** page after trying the code below,

Here is my blade code,

```
<a href="{{route('admin.delete.article',$article->id)}}" title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

Here is my route, the route has a prefix called admin

```
Route::get('/deletearticle/{$id}','App\Http\Controllers\Back\ArticleController@delete')->name('delete.article');
```

Here is my controller class, which is initially generated as a resource, however for the purpose of deleting a row from the database, a new function called delete is introduced manually. Therefore I am not using the destroy function. I am not introducing a delete method yet, so that I can see the $id on a new page as a test.

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function delete($id)
    {
        return $id;
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I am not introducing a delete method yet so that I can see the $id on a new page.. Also when I hower the mouse on the delete link object and click on it, it shows me localhost:8000/admin/deletearticle/9 on the browser, which is correct. But the page is **404 NOT FOUND** .

I would be greatful to hear from you, if you have an idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route parameters don't have a `$` in their name. `{id}` not `{$id}`.

Comment: Yes, it was that simple I could not see. Thank you very much. Do you have any idea about, where to look for this error details while testing? Seeing only a 404 page doesnt help much on locating where the mistake is.